# Read integers into an existing list

Tags: haskell

I know that `read` converts string to an integer. How do I use `read` and append to `theList` properly?

```
theList = []

inputList = do
inputNum <- getLine
if null inputNum
    then do putStrLn "Done"
    else do theList <- (read inputNum)
            inputList
```

Problem statement is `theList <- (read inputNum)`

Comment: In Haskell, lists are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values in Haskell are immutable, which means that you can't modify them after you've declared them.  Don't think of Haskell as having variables, think of it as having static values instead.

What you can do in this case is build an IO action that will return a list of all the values typed in:

```
inputList :: IO [Int]
inputList = do
    inputNum <- getLine
    if null inputNum
        then do
            putStrLn "Done"
            return []
        else do
            rest <- inputList
            let num = read inputNum
            return $ num : rest
```

Then you can use it as

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter some numbers..."
    nums <- inputList
    putStrLn "The numbers you entered from smallest to largest are:"
    let sortedNums = sort nums
    mapM_ print sortedNums
```

Comment: @derp Yes.  If you have an action `someAction :: IO a` and you see `someVar <- someAction`, then `someVar` has type `a`.  This means that `nums` has the type `[Int]`.

Comment: using `sort nums` in main doesn't seem to work for me. Giving me guff about matching `Int` with `()`

Comment: @derp Are you just calling it directly in `main` on its own line?  That won't work.  Remember, `sort` doesn't modify the list passed to it, it returns a new list that is sorted.  You'll need to do something like `let sortedNums = sort nums`.  I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Aha! Lightbulb moment. I've been far too stubborn with trying to modify lists, despite what people are telling me. The `let` command is my saving grace.

Comment: @derp It takes a while to get used to, but over time you'll learn that maybe you really didn't need all that mutable state you're used to in a language like Python or Java.  The immutability of Haskell lets you really reason about what your code is doing, which helps you to ensure that the code you're writing is correct.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot insert into an existing list.

In Haskell lists are immutable, you can create a new list from the existing list using functions like `:` and `++`.